# Jquery show this number of ul li

Tags: jquery, events, html-lists

This is probably a silly question but I googled for hours with no luck..I have some ul li like this:

```
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
```

How do I show only a specific set of li? So only 1 to 3 or 1 to 4 and hide the others? I would  like doing this according to a `var` like:

```
     var number_of_list = 5; {
            if (some_results > 5)
            {
                ...'show 5 ul li with jquery'...
}
```

If that is not possible Then I would like doing this wit an event like:

```
$(input).keyup(function() {
  number_of_list = 5;
$(ul li)....show 5 ul li...(which is number_of_list of course) ;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('ul li').hide().filter(':lt(4)').show();
```

this will start by hiding all `li` elements then show the first 4 - you can just change the number to show the first #

To use a variable, do this:

```
 var myvar = 5;
 $('ul li').hide().filter(':lt('+myvar+')').show();
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think I can put a var somewhere..? I tried `(':lt(myVar)')` but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `:gt()` (index greater than) and `:lt` (index lower than) selectors http://jsfiddle.net/blackpla9ue/sabnE/

`$('li:gt(1):lt(4)').addClass('col');` would add class 'col' to index 1-4 lis

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
​<ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pa">..</a></li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

```
 var number_of_list = 2;
 $("li").css("background", "#b4b0da")
        .filter(function (index) {
               return index >number_of_list-1; //because index starts with 0
        })
        .css("display", "none");​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jZprT/2/)

Comment: Your variable `number_of_list` is equal to 2 ... but the number of `li` elements shown in your example is 3 !!!

Comment: index start with 0 you can use return index >number_of_list -1 ;